# Is this possible to server websocket handler and normal servlet over same context?

Tags: java, servlets, websocket, servlet-filters, spring-websocket

Is this possible to serve websocket handler and normal servlet over same context?

***Sample***

```
http://localhost/appcontext/endpoint  --> serving by normal servlet
ws://localhost/appcontext/endpoint --> serving by websocket handler
```

I have tried multiple ways but can't able to do it. It seem url mapping is filtered by the context path and not by the protocol like 'http' or 'ws'. May be what I found is wrong. I was trying to see this using spring and java.

Answer (score 3):

### Short answer:

Nope, you cannot use the same path served either by servlet or websocket. Each http request to `http://localhost/appcontext/endpoint` is expected to have a specific behaviour

### Long answer:

This answer goes out of Java scope as it mainly relies on [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455), aka the websocket bible. The reason why lies in the handshake process.

**Websocket URIs**

In section 3 of RFC 6455, the websocket URI is defined as followed:

> ws-URI = "ws:" "//" host [ ":" port ] path [ "?" query ]
>
> wss-URI = "wss:" "//" host [ ":" port ] path [ "?" query ]

Leaving the URI details aside, one might actually thinks that it is possible to solely access the HTTP counterpart with only HTTP protocol.

**The handshake: client side**

<sub>*Reminder: websocket is a bidirectional protocol. Consequently, the **client** is the entity which initialises the connection. However, once the connection is established, both client and server can send a message or closes the communication. But the server and client concept is kept to know who is who*</sub>

The client initialises the handshake: "Hey server! I want to establish a webosocket communication". However, the handshake starts over http. On page 17 of RFC 6455 (section 4.1):

> 1. The handshake MUST be a valid HTTP request as specified by [RFC2616].
> 2. The method of the request MUST be GET, and the HTTP version MUST be at least 1.1.
>
>    For example, if the WebSocket URI is "ws://example.com/chat", the first line sent should be "GET /chat HTTP/1.1".
> 3. The "Request-URI" part of the request MUST match the /resource name/ defined in Section 3 (a relative URI) or be an absolute http/https URI that, when parsed, has a /resource name/, /host/, and /port/ that match the corresponding ws/wss URI.

Behind every websocket communication initialisation hides an HTTP request of the same path. To get back to your example:

1. client asks `ws://localhost/appcontext/endpoint`
2. it actually asks to `http://localhost/appcontext/endpoint` with an upgrade request and the appropriate headers defined by RFC 6455
3. server answers and only after the handshake the communication switches from `http(s)` to `ws(s)`

**The handshake: server side**

But what if you want to cheat and say "*I pretend I don't know that this is a websocket URI and I want to access the HTTP resources behind this URL*". On the server-side, your application had registered a path `http://localhost/appcontext/endpoint` for URI matching as "I'm waiting websocket connections here", similarly to web services path matching process. In section 4.2.1 of RFC 6455:

> The client’s opening handshake consists of the following parts. If the server, while reading the handshake, finds that the client did not send a handshake that matches the description below (note that as per [RFC2616], the order of the header fields is not important), including but not limited to any violations of the ABNF grammar specified for the components of the handshake, the server MUST stop processing the client’s handshake and return an HTTP response with an appropriate error code (such as 400 Bad Request).
>
> 1. An HTTP/1.1 or higher GET request, including a "Request-URI" [RFC2616] that should be interpreted as a /resource name/ defined in Section 3 (or an absolute HTTP/HTTPS URI containing the /resource name/).
> 2. A |Host| header field containing the server’s authority.
> 3. An |Upgrade| header field containing the value "websocket", treated as an ASCII case-insensitive value.

As `http://localhost/appcontext/endpoint` is registered for websocket handshake, a basic HTTP request does not include the `Upgrade` header and is then rejected by the server.

### Edit

While writing this answer, I tried it with:

1. Endpoint: `appcontext/endpoint`
2. A page: `appcontext/endpoint/index.xhtml`
3. welcome file: `index.xhtml`: so `appcontext/endpoint` redirects to `index.xhtml`

As expected, my websocket connection fails. If I change the page path from `endpoint/index.xhtml` to `endpoint2/index.xhtml`, the websocket works back.

However, I just found that http://demos.kaazing.com/echo/ uses the same URL for its websocket connection and I couldn't find why >_<

Comment: Thank for the answer. Since RFC 6455 did not mention about it, I think as long as the container can handle ,by checking the http request whether it is request for http or upgrade request to websocket, both shall be run over the same context. In your case container does not seem to handle it properly or something is missing in configuration.

Comment: Actually, that's not my understanding of RFC 6455 (and same thoughts apply to JSR-356): the server should reject any requests matching the URI which is not a websocket upgrade request. But Kaazing seems to be specialized in websocket and similar technologies. Maybe they have some custom features. Plus, they may not use Java EE as a server

Comment: You are right if the websocket container or server received other request than websocket http upgrade request, it should reject it. What I mean is that if the webserver receive normal request, it will handle it by itself, but if that was wshandshake request, it will let the websoket server handle it.In these way, http server and ws server can work hand in hand and run over same context. correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: I guess we had a wording issue. As the ws handshake starts with HTTP, the server **has** to handle both protocol at the endpoint path. There is no distinction between http server and websocket server: it's the same server which only switches protocol. Actually, your question goes out of Java scope and rather lies in HTTP/Websocket in general, hence the focus on RFC-6455 instead of JSR-356. By the way, is my answer is worth an upvote (maybe not acceptance)?

Comment: I agree with @FranXho: The websocket-server could check for the "Upgrade:" header, and if not there, pass on to "normal processing" by the servlet container.
Edit: Just checked, and it works fine with Jetty 9. Both a Servlet registered at "websocket/json", and my JSR 356 WebSocket endpoint also at that exact same location. Accessing by normal browser URL, sees the Servlet, accessing with new WebSocket(..), gets the WebSocket.